# Enable sid claim in the Keyclaok id token

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

I'm currently working on configuring Keycloak as a federated identity provider to test the OIDC back-channel logout flow.

In both id token and the logout token, they don't include the `sid` claim by default since it is an optional claim. But in the client's configuration, there's a config to enable the session identifier in the back-channel logout token. [Config to enable 'sid' claim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yj0tP.png).  If this is enabled, the logout token will have an `sid` claim, but the id token won't.

[OIDC Specification](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-backchannel-1_0.html#BCSupport) section 2.1,

> backchannel_logout_session_supported:
> OPTIONAL. Boolean value specifying whether the OP can pass a sid (session ID) Claim in the Logout Token to identify the RP session with the OP. If supported, the sid Claim is also included in ID Tokens issued by the OP. If omitted, the default value is false.

According to this, if the `sid` claim is included in the logout token, id token should also have the `sid` claim

Is there a way to include `sid` claim in the id token as well ?.
If not, what's the purpose of having an `sid` claim only in the logout token and not in the id token ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the back-channel flows, but in general you want to use KeyCloak's concept of "Mappers" to add claims into tokens. Both Identity Providers and Clients can have Mappers, depending on where you need to add data.

Clients and IdP configs will have different 'Mapper Types' available. The 'Mapper Type' field is the most important field when configuring the Mapper - it determines where the data is coming from (some session value, some user attribute, etc). We often have to write small custom implementations for new mapper types to pull some data out of the Java layer so we can put it into a token.

[image: Example of a Client Mapper]

Comment: sid value is the unique session identifier of a user on a browser or a device. 'sid' claim has to be generated by the identity provider for a particular session and added to the id token or logout token. The problem in the Keycloak is, I can get an sid in the logout token but not in the id token.
I've edited the question and added the OIDC specification section where they specify about the 'sid' claim support.

Comment: Yes I understood your question properly I was telling you where in key Cloak you can add your own claim to the token. It's very likely if they do not expose a mapper for the SID you could write your own mapper implementation which is quite easy to do and very likely all it would have to do is look up the SID for the current context

Comment: Yeah, it seems that your suggestion is the current solution for this. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Sure. I do wish there were 3-4 times the number of predefined mappers :-) Problem seems ot be everyone writes them in a proprietary context, so they don't make it back upstream